# Pig: how to exit on failure?

Tags: apache-pig

```
-- do something
store result into '$RESULT.tmp';
rmf $RESULT
mv $RESULT.tmp $RESULT
```

If exceptions thrown before `rmf $RESULT`, then the script should exit immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be achieved with the `-F` or `-stop_on_failure` command line flag. If used, Pig will stop execution when the first failed job is detected and discontinue further processing. This also means that file commands that come after a failed store in the script will not be executed (this can be used to create "done" files).

This is how the flag is used:

```
$ pig -F myscript.pig
```

or

```
$ pig -stop_on_failure myscript.pig
```

*Source:* http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.10.0/perf.html#error-handling